# If a matrix has full rank, can it be inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I read, that if a matrix is inconsistent you are able to bring it into a form where in one row there will only be zero entries, but the corresponding right hand side won't be zero, i.e. there exists a equation of the form $0x_1+0x_2+\cdots+0x_n=b_i\neq0$, which is an equality that can never be satisfied. But, if a matrix has full rank, there does not exist a row that does only contain zero elements, hence, if the matrix has full rank it cannot be inconsistent.

Is this correct?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is correct for *square* matrices.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much!

Comment: You are most welcome! I should also point out that not only do full-rank square matrices not have zero rows, but you can never produce a zero row through any sequence of elementary row operations.

Comment: Right, that's important. Thanks again

Comment: Do you want to write this comment as an answer, so i can mark this question as answered and you will get the credit?

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&4\cr0&0\cr}$ has rank two, which is the highest rank a matrix with two columns can have, so I'd say it has full rank, despite having an all-zero row.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. @TheoBendit pointed that out, too. The matrix has to be square.

Comment: If the matrix has to be square, that condition should be edited into the body of the question, not left at the end of a trail of comments. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: The question was for which matrices this statement holds. The answer is, for square matrices. Please restrain from falsely editing a finished post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Matrices* are not consistent or inconsistent, but rather *systems of equations* are.  If the  matrix $A$ corresponding to a system of equations $Ax=b$ is square, and has full rank, then the system will be consistent, since such a matrix corresponds to an isomorphism, and hence is surjective.